# how to convert string data from backend to simple text in reactJs. So, that html tags like <br> can take effect

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

API backend response is in the form of JSON. Some JSON fields contains html fields like 
. React is rendering this values as string, because of this html tags like 
 are not taking effect. How to handle this in reactjs.

```
For Ex. "hdjhjwjkhjj <br> hdnbjbj" to hdjhjwjkhjj <br> hdnbjbj .
```

Comment: Ummm why not? `element.innerHTML = "hdjhjwjkhjj <br> hdnbjbj"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop, like this:

```
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'some <br> HTML <br> string'}}/>
```

[Here's the official documentation for it.](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: This solves the problem. I was searching for a way to solve this problem without using this method. But, it seems there is no other way available.

Comment: There are also libraries like https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react, but this solution depends only on React.

Comment: I know the solution of DoMiNeLa10 solves the problem, but the real issue is that you shouldn't be using `<br />` tags at all. It is 2018, use bootstrap, or flex, or any grid system to layout your content and paragraphs to organize your text. Cleaner code, easier to maintain, better code.

Comment: @versvs There are cases where you'll need a `<br/>` even when using bootstrap or anything like it. Consider addresses in which you should expect explicit newlines to separate parts of them. It makes sense semantically, and it's the proper way to do it.